# Is it correct that sometimes I get angle brackets in "From" field of an e-mail message?

Tags: email, email-validation

My software is working with incoming e-mail from the one and only particular sender (let it be SantaClaus@hetnet.nl). According to RFC-2616 section 14 "From" header

> MAY be used for logging purposes and
>   **as a means for identifying the source of invalid or unwanted
>   requests.**

That's exactly what I needed, so I wrote a code, which ignores all  the messages where "From" field doesn't equal `SantaClaus@hetnet.nl`. It worked good, but one day things changed, and now all the messages form Santa Claus contains a different string in "From" field (exactly `<SantaClaus@hetnet.nl>`). 
I already fixed my code, but I just wonder, is this header legal? Because the same RFC-2616 section 14 says:

> The address SHOULD be machine-usable,
>   as defined by "mailbox" in RFC 822 [9]
>   as updated by RFC 1123 [8]:
>
> ```
>    From   = "From" ":" mailbox
> ```
>
> An example is:
>
> ```
>    From: webmaster@w3.org
> ```

Note the absense of angle brackets. But at the same time, many e-mail messages I receive on my Gmail account has something like this in the "From" field: `"Santa Claus" <santaclaus@hetnet.nl>`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[RFC-822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822) allows email addresses to be specified either by a pure email-style address, called an "*addr-spec*" (e.g., `name@host.domain`); or by using a nickname ("*phrase*") with the email-style address (the "*addr-spec*") enclosed in angle brackets (`Foo Bar <foobar@host.domain>`). Your sender has gone from the first format to the second format, although here the nickname part seems to be empty.

By the way, RFC-2616 is for HTTP; you're looking at the definition of an optional, and (I imagine) rarely-used, From: header in the HTTP protocol. That doesn't seem to have any direct relevance on email formats.

Comment: Yep, RFC-2616 was a result of bad googling, now I see that I needed the RFC you mentioned (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc822) and that `Foo Bar <foobar@host.domain>` is correct according to standard.